# .html() in my angular directive is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am converting my code to angular and I need help with creating a directive. I am trying to convert the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
"use strict";

$('#cool-navigation').append('<ul class="navigation">' + $('.navigation').html() + '</ul>');
});
```

to

```
app.directive('coolnavigation', function () {
    return { template: '<ul class="navigation">' + $('.navigation').html() + '</ul>' };
});
```

This is the HTML. The first view is the shell and the second is called topnav

```
<section data-cc-sizer data-ng-controller="shell as vm">

<!-- Sticky Nav -->
<div data-coolnavigation class="sticky-navigation" id="sticky-navigation"></div>
<!-- Sticky Nav -->

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="top_wrapper clearfix">
        <header class="top-header shadow">
            <div data-ng-include="'/app/layout/topnav.html'"></div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="content">
    <div id="wrapper" data-ng-view></div>
</section>
</section>

<section  data-cc-topnav data-ng-controller="topnav as vm">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-class">
            <nav>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li data-ng-repeat="r in vm.navRoutes">
                        <a href="#{{r.url}}" class="{{r.className}}" data-ng-bind-html="r.config.settings.content"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</section>
```

I think I am missing something with the .html(). Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('.navigation')` looks for an element in the DOM with class navigation. It seems you're calling it before the element is actually there?

Comment: You could be right. I am getting an "undefined" when it comes up. Any suggestions on creating an angular equivalent to the jquery on the top?

Comment: can you show us the html that you try to transform?

Comment: ok, you may put the li's with data-ng-repeat in your template string. is there a special reason why you not write the ul class navigation as a child of the div with data-coolnavigation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to `$('.navigation')` in your template which is a HTML block with some Angular code inside. Your template has no guarantee that Angular has rendered that bit yet, that's why we use directives in the first place. That's why $('.navigation') is empty. If you're trying to convert this from jQuery, then stop using jQuery.

A directive has a `link` function which happens after compiling. Think of the `link` function like `document.ready` in jQuery, but for a specific element or directive. Of course you're trying to refer to a completely different element so you won't know when that's done. That points to a larger problem... why are you trying to copy the DOM from one structure to another? Just put that DOM in your template and call it a day.

Comment: app.directive('coolnavigation', function() {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'           
    };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.append('<ul class="navigation">' + $('.navigation').html() + '</ul>');
        }
    });

Comment: Like I said, that's because you're trying to grab something from another location in the DOM. Your directive would need to be on a parent to garauntee compilation. REMOVE the jQuery, just put `<li data-ng-repeat="r in vm.navRoutes">
                        <a href="#{{r.url}}" class="{{r.className}}" data-ng-bind-html="r.config.settings.content"></a>
                    </li>` in your template and call it day.

Comment: Ok. Let me try it out.